# How to show that if a function follows this condition in a closed region then its bounded in this region?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ follow this condition:

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that
>   $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ when  $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $x,y\in D$, where $D$ is a closed region.

How to use the above condition to show that $f(x)$ follows the condition

> There exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in D$

Comment: Should we assume that $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Is $D$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: so $D$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$? In this case I don't believe that $f$ is bounded on $D$.

Comment: If you mean (topologically) closed, it's false; consider the identity function with $D=\mathbb{R}$. If by closed you mean a bounded region (or a closed interval), this is a dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975339/let-f-be-a-real-uniformly-continuous-function-on-the-bounded-set-e-in-math/1975374#1975374

Comment: I still don't believe it. Perhaps you mean $D$ is a closed interval, in which case this is certainly true.

Comment: @MrDi What is said in arabic ?

Comment: $D$ may not be a subset of $R$. It could take some complex values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true !

Take $f(x)=\ln(x)$ on $[1,+\infty [$. You have that $$|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|\leq |x-y|,$$
for all $x,y\geq 1$, but $f$ is not bounded.